# How to capture Yahoo Groups message attachments?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, yahoo-api

I need to export both message data and the attachments from a Yahoo Group. I was looking at an export tool here:
[Yahoo Group forum data exporter](https://github.com/jonbartlett/yahoo-groups-export)

I'm seeing a remark that "... no obvious way to access message attachments", but I seem to recall other remarks elsewhere about grabbing them. Not to mention, it seems that we could still scrape them if needed.

Is there an available direct way to get Yahoo Group message attachments?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This kind of question is not what this site is for. This site is for programming questions, so if you had written a scraper and your code for getting attachments wasn't working you would come here and ask for help fixing your code. I recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn what kinds of questions are permitted here. This question will likely be closed because it is not appropriate for this site as written.

Comment: I don't understand. I see a lot of other questions like this here. This question is very valid since I'm asking for a specific question regarding possibly using the API to pull in the attachments or otherwise.

Comment: Again, please take the tour and read the help topics you’ll find there about what questions are and are not on topic. This question is not on topic nor are questions like it. It’s too broad, it’s unclear, it’s asking for a specific tool, and it has no example to reproduce. (these are all covered in the aforementioned help topics)

Comment: Sorry, even after the tour this is as clear as mud. Especially after reviewing actual content and doing some searches. I can come up with about 50 examples that are contrary to your words. :( This is insane and I want nothing to do with a community like this if w're going to be fighting from square one about something that's clearly contradictory.

Comment: I hope you will not be frustrated into leaving the site. You can trust me on this: [this question is off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [these types of questions are on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You can read more about [asking questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Although you may have found counter-examples, those questions are also off-topic here. If you reworked this question to "I'm trying to do x and expect y to happen but z happens instead, and here's my code to reproduce it" then it'd be on topic.